# Switching between open apps and desktop screen Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

On Windows 8.1 it is really easy to switch between open apps and desktop screen. And when I mention "desktop screen" I do mean actual desktop screen.

According to one description available on internet regarding Windows 8.1:

- Press Alt + Tab. A dialog box shows all open apps and programs (and the desktop, too)

Well this (desktop too) thingy is missing in Windows 10.

For Example: The first small screen from the right (having flower), shows my desktop screen on windows 8.1

[image]

On the other hand this is missing in my other PC having Windows 10 Education edition.

I'd be thankful to anyone who knows any workaround that I can get back this way of moving between open apps and 'desktop screen' on Windows 10.

Comment: This behavior hasn't changed.

Comment: The purpose of above question is to find any workaround to this issue.

Comment: `Windows Key + D` beyond that use third-party software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple solution:
Just press Windows Key+D or you can also click in the corner of the taskbar, there is a thin hardly visible bar on the very end right side of the taskbar which does the same.

Comment: Yes I was unaware of Windows Key+D and above comment by @Ramhound told me about it.

Comment: Great, I don't know why Ramhound is putting answers in the comments. It should go as an answer.